# Use JwtService inside RolesGuard to decode JWT token and get user roles without using passport

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs

I really don't know what should I do to resolve my problem. I tried implement AuthGuard for protected routes in controller. I want to check user role in **roles.guard.ts** and if he has one of required the controller will be open for him. My structure looks like:

```
- src
  - auth
    auth.controller.ts
    auth.service.ts
    auth.module.ts
  - roles
    roles.decorator.ts
    roles.guard.ts
  app.module.ts
  main.ts
```

In **auth.service.ts** I'm using JwtService to generate token and verify token and it works as well:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService
  ) {
  }

  findUser(id: number): string {
    if (id === 0) throw new Error("User not available");

    return "martin";
  }

  async generateToken(email: string, role: string[]): Promise<string> {
    const payload = { email: email, role: role };

    return this.jwtService.sign(payload, { expiresIn: '24h', secret: process.env['JWT_SECRET'] });
  }

  async validateToken(token: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const isValidToken = await this.jwtService.verify(token, { secret: process.env['JWT_SECRET'] });

    return !!isValidToken;
  }
}
```

In **auth.controller.ts** I used `@Roles` decorator to define required user role:

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Param, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Roles } from '../roles/roles.decorator';
import { RolesGuard } from '../roles/roles.guard';

@UseGuards(RolesGuard)
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  @Get(':id')
  @Roles('admin')
  async findUser(@Body() id: number) {
    return this.authService.findUser(id);
  }

  @Get('generate')
  async generateToken() {
    return this.authService.generateToken('localhost', ['admin', 'user', 'seller'] );
  }
}
```

And my **auth.module.ts** is nothing special, the same as in the docs:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Module({
  imports: [JwtModule.register({
    secret: process.env['JWT_SECRET']
  })],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

And in the **roles.guard.ts** which is activated to check role from `@Roles` I want to use JwtService to decode my JWT token stored in cookies, so I wrote this code:

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private jwtService: JwtService
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) return true;

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.headers;

    if (!user.auth_token) return false;

    const matchRoles = () => this.jwtService.verify(user.auth_token, { secret: process.env['JWT_SECRET'] });

    console.log(matchRoles());
  }
}
```

But Nest return error in while compile code:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RolesGuard (Reflector,?). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [1] is available in the RolesGuard context.

Potential solutions:
- If JwtService is a provider, is it part of the current Rol
esGuard?
- If JwtService is exported from a separate @Module, is that
 module imported within RolesGuard?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JwtService */ ]
  })
```

At the end my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { RolesGuard } from './roles/roles.guard';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: ['.env.development', '.env.production'],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      entities: [],
      synchronize: true
    }),
    AuthModule,
    RolesGuard
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {
  }
}
```

And I don't know what to do? Another module only for `roles.guard.ts` or what? I really don't want to use passport and implement his strategy, when I should can use (in theory) JwtService properties. Or maybe I should move `roles.*` files to `auth` directory?

Comment: The same error I am also having now. My prediction is nest doesn't support multiple instantiation inside the constructor of the RolesGuard (inheritor of CanActivate). I am not sure the actual thing, this is just a suspect.

Answer (score 0):

`RolesGuard` should not be in the `imports` array. The only thing that should **ever** go in the `imports` array are [Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules). All Nest enhancers ([Filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters), [Guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards), [Interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors), and [Pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes)) exist outside of the `providers` array as well **unless you are globally binding them with their respective** `APP_*` **constants**.